# ios7 The splash screen has a white bar at the bottom

Tags: cordova, ios7

I am facing an issue since i passed to ios 7:

The splash screen has a white bar at the bottom of the device screen.
I think this may be related to the status bar changes on iOS 7 which is always visible in the App, and i'm not able to make it hidden.

on forums they suggested many parameters to set in config.xml to hide the status bar  but it doesn't work.

P.S: i'm using phonegap build

thanks

Comment: what version of phonegap do you use?

Answer (score 2):

**Up until PhoneGap 3.0:**

In the **CDVSplashScreen.m** file look for this line

```
imgBounds.origin.y -= statusFrame.size.height;
```

and change it to this:

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"7.0")) { 
    imgBounds.origin.y -= statusFrame.size.height;
}
```

also add these lines to the top of the same file:

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(v)([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(v)([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedDescending)
```

This will remove the white bar from the bottom.

**From PhoneGap 3.1:**
this is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Go to XXXX-info.plist and ensure the 'Status bar is initially hidden' parameter is set to YES

Answer (score 0):

It might be your default image dimensions. With iOS 7, the default image size should include status bar height (before it did not). E.g for iPhone 5, the portrait version should be 640 x 1136.

Reference: [App Launch (Default) Images](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12)